# Application crashes when I use Mongo with Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, mongodb, maven

My application crashes at start with an error:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 60; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'.

My context.xml looks like this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
http##://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http##://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http##://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
http##://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

 <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="localhost" port="27017"/>

 <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
 <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
 <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="ProcessOrderManagement"/>
 </bean>
```

My Pom.xml looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please ignore the two # sign, as I was not able to paste a link as my rep is not 10, I entered that sign,
Anyway, My application crashes after giving the above error. What am I doing wrong?

Updated XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation="

                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
            ">


<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="localhost" port="27017"/>


<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
<constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
<constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="ProcessOrderManagement"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: /data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd  instead of this just define /data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd  and try again

Comment: @BilboBaggins Have tried that, same error. Sorry did not mentioned that I tried that.

Comment: You need post your `context.xml` properly. The full file if possible, or at least first 30 lines. Character-by-character. It is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear your context.xml is either pasted wrong or your error is that your context.xml doesn't open properly. You are missing the opening xml document tags. Note top of this example.

UPDATED: Also note the need for spring context namespace if you don't have that.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
          xsi:schemaLocation=
          "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
    <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: For reference, that example from spring docs found here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-xml-config

Comment: I have updated the XML, my application runs fine when I remove the  xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo" and

http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd

Comment: Hmm, thats odd, that schema does exist, you can navigate to it in a browser.